# how to include a php variable as part of a table name?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where I needed to use separate table names for each of my clients because the data has to be updated all the time with a manual import.

example:
kansas_users
newyork_users

I have set a global variable as $client which will create the state name on all pages so if I echo "$client"; then I will see "kansas" for example on any page.

I would like to include this variable as part of my SQL query if possible to make it easier to code:

```
SELECT "nick, firstname, lastname, cell 
FROM database.$client_members 
where active =1 and id = $user->id";
```

Is this possible or even safe to do?

Comment: *"where I needed to use separate table names for each of my clients"* - Good Lord, why would you want to do that?

Comment: what isn't working for you here? You didn't tell us that.

Comment: *Is this possible or even safe to do?* Possible - yes, safe - possibly.

Comment: they have to send me their updated membership data all the time. Using one table for all clients in this manner would be a nightmare to have to ensure I wipe only the correct client data and then import without deleting wrong data.  I am currently rethinking this method though.

Comment: Your current code seams pretty prone to SQL injection attacks..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible you can do some thing like below

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$client = 'kansas';    

$table_name = "database." . $conn->real_escape_string($client) . "_members";

$query = sprintf("SELECT nick, firstname, lastname, cell 
FROM %s WHERE active = 1 and id = ?", $table_name);

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $user->id);
```

But i think you should seriously consider [normalizing](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/an-introduction-to-database-normalization/) your database to avoid such issues

Comment: even if all of these queries are behind password on a very limited-access website?

Comment: @user2554201 what do you mean?

Comment: It's not possible to prepare a table name in PHP with MySQLi it's is also not possible in PDO..

Comment: @RaymondNijland i have edited again and thank you for the heads up on that one